# Matlab complex matrix magnitude

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I have a matrix S something like:

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

Then I make `a=complex(S{2},S{3})` and wanted to find the `abs(a);`. This is not possible in MATLAB as `a` is not an integer - it is a matrix. How can I get the magnitude of each row of matrix `a`?

PS: the matrix is read from a text file using `textscan()` as `S = textscan(fileID,'%d %d %d', 'delimiter','\t');`.

Second question:

Assuming again hav the following S matrix.

```
1  4  7  2  1
2  5  8  3  4
3  6  9  6  8
```

Now I wanted to arrange them in such way that column 2,3 and 4,5 alternate like this:

```
4  2
7  1
5  3
8  4
6  6
9  8
```

How can I do that without using a loop?
Thanks.

Comment: I am confused.  If `S` is a matrix, why are you using cell notation (`{}`) to access elements?  What exactly is `S{2}` and `S{3}` doing?  Are you trying to make the second column the real component while the third column the complex component?... OK, I think I know why. You are using `textscan` which will delimit each number into individual cell elements in `S`.  Before I proceed, please confirm that `S` is a **cell** matrix.

Comment: textscan return cell array, that is why the cell notation. Otherwise you understand me correctly.

Comment: I have provided my answer.  Good luck!

Comment: How about `a=complex(cell2mat(S{2}),cell2mat(S{3}))` and then doing `abs(a)`. Assuming S is something like: `S={{1;2;3} {5;6;7} {8;9;10}}`. So `S{1}` is a cell array of columns. `S` can also be like `S={{1,2,3};{5,6,7};{8,9,10}}` and it will still work.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - That can work, but due to the `%d` delimiter in `textscan`, each number is represented as `int32`.  As such, the matrix needs to be casted / converted to a floating-point datatype before `abs` can be used.

Comment: btw, you can use `CollectOutput` option with `textscan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going with my assumption in the comments, I'm going to assume that the second column consists of your real component of your matrix while the third column consists of your imaginary components.  Your matrix `S` is actually a **cell** array of elements.  You don't need to use `complex` then `abs`.  You can simply take each of the columns, individually square them, add them together and take the square root.  What I would do is convert the cell array into a 2D matrix, cast it to **double** to allow for floating point precision when finding the magnitude, and do what I just did above.  This is necessary because `abs` and `sqrt` will only work for floating-point numbers.  Your elements in `S` are already `int32` due to the `%d` delimiter from `textread`.  In other words:

```
Smat = double(cell2mat(S));
realComp = Smat(:,2);
imagComp = Smat(:,3);
mag = sqrt(realComp.^2 + imagComp.^2);
```

`mag` will thus return the magnitude of each row for you, assuming that the second column is the real component and the third component is the imaginary component as we specified.

---

However, if you're **dead set** on using `complex` and `abs`, you can do it like so:

```
Smat = double(cell2mat(S));
imagNumbers = complex(Smat(:,2), Smat(:,3));
mag = abs(imagNumbers);
```

This should still give you the same results as we talked about above.

---

## Edit

Seeing your edit in your post above, we can achieve that quite easily by subsetting the matrix, then applying `reshape` to each part of the matrix you want.  In other words:

```
Smat = double(cell2mat(S));
realMat = Smat(:,2:3); %// Grab second and third columns
imagMat = Smat(:,4:5); %// Grab fourth and fifth columns
realCol = reshape(realMat.', [], 1); % // Form the columns like you specified
imagCol = reshape(imagMat.', [], 1);

finalMatrix = [realCol imagCol];
```

`finalMatrix` should contain those two columns that you specified above in a single matrix.

Comment: Great, thanks! But I tried to make Smat = int32(cell2mat(S)); it is not possible, why?

Comment: @user2413711 You can certainly cast `S` to `int32` but `abs` or `sqrt` **will not work**.  These functions only work for **floating-point** numbers, which is why I casted your matrix to `double` before I created the magnitude of each number.  Your elements in `S` are already `int32` due to the `%d` delimiter from `textread`.

Comment: @user2413711 - You're very welcome.  Please accept my answer if I have helped you!  Click on the checkmark icon at the top of my post towards the left and below the up and down voting buttons.

Comment: Hey, I have one last question. Check out my original post.

Comment: @user2413711 - Do you want to create a single column vector that contains those numbers?

Comment: I want one column out of the two each(2,3 and 4,5) then I will do the previous abs() thing. Got it?

Comment: OK, I see it.  I'll edit my answer.  Give me three minutes again.

Comment: @user2413711 - Done.  Good luck!